# display message box when sheet has unsaved changes while Sheet change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data loader using a button event for a sheet. When the user changes from one sheet to the other without saving the data we need to show them a prompt for saving.

Could you help on this?

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforesave-event-excel) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)

Comment: why don'y you just save the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will check when the last time the workbook was saved, then you can do a comparison with current date/time to see how long ago it was saved:

```
Sub CheckSaved()
    Dim sLastTime String
    On Error GoTo NotSaved
    sLastTime = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("last save time")
    MsgBox sLastTime, vbInformation, "Last Saved"
    Exit Sub
NotSaved:
    MsgBox "File not saved", vbInformation, "Last Saved"
End Sub
```

To execute the code when a Sheet is selected, you can call the code like below, add the same Call to all your sheeets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call CheckSaved
End Sub
```